# Windows 7 - mouse wheel on Window Explorer scrolls 3 lines at the time

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

My mouse wheel scrolls three rows of icons at the time, which is too much. Is there a way to reduce this?

Answer (score 3):

This answer assumes you don't have any fancy mouse with it's own drivers/software outside the control of Windows.

In Control Panel, click Mouse

In the Wheel section, change the option to what you want

[image]

Also, [try this KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/303091)

Comment: That had an effect on web browsing also, is there a way to change only for Windows Explorer?

Comment: Try a reboot, and then, see my updated my answer @cholomaldito

Comment: @cholomaldito: If your mouse has it's own driver software from the manufacturer, that may give you the option of setting up application-specific settings. My Logitech does, for example.

Comment: Is there some way to change it in command line?